# Query for java client

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to construct this json using `QueryBuilders` but the "query" key is missing from the json, can anybody help me ?

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "disable_coord": false,
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1.0
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `query` wrap, you can use `SearchSourceBuilder` with `QueryBuilder`, maybe like:

```
BoolQueryBuilder must = boolQuery().adjustPureNegative(true).disableCoord(false).boost(1.0f)
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
searchSourceBuilder.query(must);
XContentBuilder xContentBuilder = jsonBuilder();
searchSourceBuilder.toXContent(xContentBuilder, ToXContent.EMPTY_PARAMS);
System.out.println(xContentBuilder.string());
```

Comment: {"query":{ "bool" :{ "disable_coord":false, "adjust_pure_negative":true, "boost": 1.0 }} } in this json the key "query" is still missing

Comment: @NitinChand, Sorry misunderstand, I have updated my answer, hopeful it's helpful

Comment: Thanks a million :)